# SAPUI5 - Destinations for SAPUI5 applications

Tags: sapui5

I have recently started with SAPUI5, and have been following various Blogs and tutorials. I have a few queries:

1. We maintain Destinations in the HCP Cockpit, and then use these destinations for oData services in the web IDE. How are the Destinations maintained for the different landscapes(Dev --> QA --> PRD), so that the SAPUI5 app(s) connect to the right environment?
2. How can we maintain destinations in Eclipse?

Answer (score 6):

Technically you need a destination for each enviroment. But the correct way to do is mapping your HCP accounts with 3-tiers landscape and use **the same desination name** for the 3 of them.

So, you have 3 NetWeaver systems (i.e. S1D, S1Q and S1P) and 3 HCP landscapes as well (H1D, H1Q, H1P)

Then create a destination called, for example, 'myDestination' pointing for each landscape:

```
  in H1D -> myDestination points to -> S1D
  in H1Q -> myDestination points to -> S1Q
  in H1P -> myDestination points to -> S1P
```

Therefore when you deploy your app in H1D, and calls 'myDestination' it points to the Dev NW system, the you transport your app to H1Q and when the app calls 'myDestination' it points to the Qual NW system, etc etc

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. How can we maintain destinations(or achieve similar functionality) when working on Eclipse?

Comment: Just Setup your Eclipse IDE like described [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/Cloud/en-US/e815ca4cbb5710148376c549fd74c0db.html)

And use the API like described [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/cca91383641e40ffbe03bdc78f00f681/Cloud/en-US/462dbffef4614044b5c727c9de37672e.html)